# Consultar base de datos con SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Estoy tratando de aplicar una consulta a una tabla, utilizando la ORM sqlalchemy en una base de datos ya creada con mysql, con el siguiente codigo:

```
eng = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://host='localhost', user='root', passwd='...',port='3307', database='Nomina_jul15'")

Session = sessionmaker (bind=eng)
session = Session()  

def Ver():
    print("Estas en la Opcion Ver Empleados ")
    print("")
    print("idEmpleados \t numdocEmp  \t nombreEmp \t salbasicEmp \t fechaingEmp \t nombre_eps \t nombre_afp \t fechanacEmp \t sexoEmp")
    print("============================================================================================================================")
    for Empleados in session:

        empleados = session.query(Empleados).get(Empleados)
        print(str(empleados))

    session.close()
    print('')
```

Y solo me sale el encabezado del informe:

```
Estas en la Opcion Ver Empleados 

idEmpleados      numdocEmp       nombreEmp   salbasicEmp     fechaingEmp     nombre_eps      nombre_afp      fechanacEmp     sexoEmp
============================================================================================================================
```

No se si se debe a que no hice con la creación de la base de datos utilizando SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las sesiones sirven para establecer la conexión a la base de datos, estás tratando de iterar la sesión cuando lo que deberías iterar es un query. Este query lo creas usando la sesión que ya tienes definida:

```
def Ver():
    print("Estas en la Opcion Ver Empleados ")
    print("")
    print("idEmpleados \t numdocEmp  \t nombreEmp \t salbasicEmp \t fechaingEmp \t nombre_eps \t nombre_afp \t fechanacEmp \t sexoEmp")
    print("============================================================================================================================")
    for empleado in session.query(Empleados):
        print(empleado.id) # Imprime en pantalla los campos que necesites

    session.close()
    print('')
```

Con esto estás iterando cada registro de la tabla sin ningún orden en específico. Si, por ejemplo, quisieras ordernarlos por el nombre puedes usar:

```
for empleado in session.query(Empleados).order_by(Empleados.nombre):
    print(empleado.id)
```

Comment: pero es que la tabla esta ordenada segun secuencia del encabezado del informe, inicialmente asi es como lo necesito.

Comment: @Jsierra2017 eso solo era una aclaración, puedes hacerlo sin ordernar. ¿De qué informa estás hablando? Tu puedes presentar los datos en el ordern que crees conveniente. Yo me refería al orden del query.

Comment: ese print al final me esta generando error de syntaxis  print('  ')?

Comment: ok, entendido el orden

Comment: @Jsierra2017 perdón, el comentario esta mal ubicado. Ya actualicé la respuesta

Comment: @Jsierra2017 ¿funcionó?

Comment: Todavia no? Me esta generando error

Comment: @Jsierra2017 actualiza la pregunta con el error que te sale

Comment: print('')
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: este es el error que genera, hay que tener en cuenta, que esta es la opcion ver, de un menu = textwrap.dedent, de 5 opciones, pero con el codigo anterior de la pregunta no generar error, solo que no me trae los datos de la tabla?

Comment: ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: cunado desactivo el print(' ') me sale ese error

Comment: con # print(' ')